# Custom callback function for jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, plugins, callback

Trying to implement [this example](http://tympanus.net/Development/3DGallery/index3.html) into my project. I have no deep jquery knowledges and didn't work with javascript objects before.

What I need is, simple modification on this plugin so that, when slide changes to call some function (callback feature).

[Here is jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uujv7jcd/3/)

I can't figure out where to modify.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

And here is JS (please better look at jsfiddle, its too long, pasted here because of stackoverflow requirements)

```
(function( $, undefined ) {
    $.Gallery               = function( options, element ) {

        this.$el    = $( element );
        this._init( options );

    };

    $.Gallery.defaults      = {
        current     : 0,    // index of current item
        autoplay    : false,// slideshow on / off
        interval    : 2000  // time between transitions
    };

    $.Gallery.prototype     = {
        _init               : function( options ) {

            this.options        = $.extend( true, {}, $.Gallery.defaults, options );

            // support for 3d / 2d transforms and transitions
            this.support3d      = Modernizr.csstransforms3d;
            this.support2d      = Modernizr.csstransforms;
            this.supportTrans   = Modernizr.csstransitions;

            this.$wrapper       = this.$el.find('.dg-wrapper');

            this.$items         = this.$wrapper.children();
            this.itemsCount     = this.$items.length;

            this.$nav           = this.$el.find('nav');
            this.$navPrev       = this.$nav.find('.dg-prev');
            this.$navNext       = this.$nav.find('.dg-next');

            // minimum of 3 items
            if( this.itemsCount < 3 ) {

                this.$nav.remove();
                return false;

            }   

            this.current        = this.options.current;

            this.isAnim         = false;

            this.$items.css({
                'opacity'   : 0,
                'visibility': 'hidden'
            });

            this._validate();

            this._layout();

            // load the events
            this._loadEvents();

            // slideshow
            if( this.options.autoplay ) {

                this._startSlideshow();

            }

        },
        _validate           : function() {

            if( this.options.current < 0 || this.options.current > this.itemsCount - 1 ) {

                this.current = 0;

            }   

        },
        _layout             : function() {

            // current, left and right items
            this._setItems();

            // current item is not changed
            // left and right one are rotated and translated
            var leftCSS, rightCSS, currentCSS;

            if( this.support3d && this.supportTrans ) {

                leftCSS     = {
                    '-webkit-transform' : 'translateX(-350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(45deg)',
                    '-moz-transform'    : 'translateX(-350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(45deg)',
                    '-o-transform'      : 'translateX(-350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(45deg)',
                    '-ms-transform'     : 'translateX(-350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(45deg)',
                    'transform'         : 'translateX(-350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(45deg)'
                };

                rightCSS    = {
                    '-webkit-transform' : 'translateX(350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                    '-moz-transform'    : 'translateX(350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                    '-o-transform'      : 'translateX(350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                    '-ms-transform'     : 'translateX(350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                    'transform'         : 'translateX(350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(-45deg)'
                };

                leftCSS.opacity     = 1;
                leftCSS.visibility  = 'visible';
                rightCSS.opacity    = 1;
                rightCSS.visibility = 'visible';

            }
            else if( this.support2d && this.supportTrans ) {

                leftCSS     = {
                    '-webkit-transform' : 'translate(-350px) scale(0.8)',
                    '-moz-transform'    : 'translate(-350px) scale(0.8)',
                    '-o-transform'      : 'translate(-350px) scale(0.8)',
                    '-ms-transform'     : 'translate(-350px) scale(0.8)',
                    'transform'         : 'translate(-350px) scale(0.8)'
                };

                rightCSS    = {
                    '-webkit-transform' : 'translate(350px) scale(0.8)',
                    '-moz-transform'    : 'translate(350px) scale(0.8)',
                    '-o-transform'      : 'translate(350px) scale(0.8)',
                    '-ms-transform'     : 'translate(350px) scale(0.8)',
                    'transform'         : 'translate(350px) scale(0.8)'
                };

                currentCSS  = {
                    'z-index'           : 999
                };

                leftCSS.opacity     = 1;
                leftCSS.visibility  = 'visible';
                rightCSS.opacity    = 1;
                rightCSS.visibility = 'visible';

            }

            this.$leftItm.css( leftCSS || {} );
            this.$rightItm.css( rightCSS || {} );

            this.$currentItm.css( currentCSS || {} ).css({
                'opacity'   : 1,
                'visibility': 'visible'
            }).addClass('dg-center');

        },
        _setItems           : function() {

            this.$items.removeClass('dg-center');

            this.$currentItm    = this.$items.eq( this.current );
            this.$leftItm       = ( this.current === 0 ) ? this.$items.eq( this.itemsCount - 1 ) : this.$items.eq( this.current - 1 );
            this.$rightItm      = ( this.current === this.itemsCount - 1 ) ? this.$items.eq( 0 ) : this.$items.eq( this.current + 1 );

            if( !this.support3d && this.support2d && this.supportTrans ) {

                this.$items.css( 'z-index', 1 );
                this.$currentItm.css( 'z-index', 999 );

            }

            // next & previous items
            if( this.itemsCount > 3 ) {

                // next item
                this.$nextItm       = ( this.$rightItm.index() === this.itemsCount - 1 ) ? this.$items.eq( 0 ) : this.$rightItm.next();
                this.$nextItm.css( this._getCoordinates('outright') );

                // previous item
                this.$prevItm       = ( this.$leftItm.index() === 0 ) ? this.$items.eq( this.itemsCount - 1 ) : this.$leftItm.prev();
                this.$prevItm.css( this._getCoordinates('outleft') );

            }

        },
        _loadEvents         : function() {

            var _self   = this;

            this.$navPrev.on( 'click.gallery', function( event ) {

                if( _self.options.autoplay ) {

                    clearTimeout( _self.slideshow );
                    _self.options.autoplay  = false;

                }

                _self._navigate('prev');
                return false;

            });

            this.$navNext.on( 'click.gallery', function( event ) {

                if( _self.options.autoplay ) {

                    clearTimeout( _self.slideshow );
                    _self.options.autoplay  = false;

                }

                _self._navigate('next');
                return false;

            });

            this.$wrapper.on( 'webkitTransitionEnd.gallery transitionend.gallery OTransitionEnd.gallery', function( event ) {

                _self.$currentItm.addClass('dg-center');
                _self.$items.removeClass('dg-transition');
                _self.isAnim    = false;

            });

        },
        _getCoordinates     : function( position ) {

            if( this.support3d && this.supportTrans ) {

                switch( position ) {
                    case 'outleft':
                        return {
                            '-webkit-transform' : 'translateX(-450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(45deg)',
                            '-moz-transform'    : 'translateX(-450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(45deg)',
                            '-o-transform'      : 'translateX(-450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(45deg)',
                            '-ms-transform'     : 'translateX(-450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(45deg)',
                            'transform'         : 'translateX(-450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(45deg)',
                            'opacity'           : 0,
                            'visibility'        : 'hidden'
                        };
                        break;
                    case 'outright':
                        return {
                            '-webkit-transform' : 'translateX(450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                            '-moz-transform'    : 'translateX(450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                            '-o-transform'      : 'translateX(450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                            '-ms-transform'     : 'translateX(450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                            'transform'         : 'translateX(450px) translateZ(-300px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                            'opacity'           : 0,
                            'visibility'        : 'hidden'
                        };
                        break;
                    case 'left':
                        return {
                            '-webkit-transform' : 'translateX(-350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(45deg)',
                            '-moz-transform'    : 'translateX(-350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(45deg)',
                            '-o-transform'      : 'translateX(-350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(45deg)',
                            '-ms-transform'     : 'translateX(-350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(45deg)',
                            'transform'         : 'translateX(-350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(45deg)',
                            'opacity'           : 1,
                            'visibility'        : 'visible'
                        };
                        break;
                    case 'right':
                        return {
                            '-webkit-transform' : 'translateX(350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                            '-moz-transform'    : 'translateX(350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                            '-o-transform'      : 'translateX(350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                            '-ms-transform'     : 'translateX(350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                            'transform'         : 'translateX(350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(-45deg)',
                            'opacity'           : 1,
                            'visibility'        : 'visible'
                        };
                        break;
                    case 'center':
                        return {
                            '-webkit-transform' : 'translateX(0px) translateZ(0px) rotateY(0deg)',
                            '-moz-transform'    : 'translateX(0px) translateZ(0px) rotateY(0deg)',
                            '-o-transform'      : 'translateX(0px) translateZ(0px) rotateY(0deg)',
                            '-ms-transform'     : 'translateX(0px) translateZ(0px) rotateY(0deg)',
                            'transform'         : 'translateX(0px) translateZ(0px) rotateY(0deg)',
                            'opacity'           : 1,
                            'visibility'        : 'visible'
                        };
                        break;
                };

            }
            else if( this.support2d && this.supportTrans ) {

                switch( position ) {
                    case 'outleft':
                        return {
                            '-webkit-transform' : 'translate(-450px) scale(0.7)',
                            '-moz-transform'    : 'translate(-450px) scale(0.7)',
                            '-o-transform'      : 'translate(-450px) scale(0.7)',
                            '-ms-transform'     : 'translate(-450px) scale(0.7)',
                            'transform'         : 'translate(-450px) scale(0.7)',
                            'opacity'           : 0,
                            'visibility'        : 'hidden'
                        };
                        break;
                    case 'outright':
                        return {
                            '-webkit-transform' : 'translate(450px) scale(0.7)',
                            '-moz-transform'    : 'translate(450px) scale(0.7)',
                            '-o-transform'      : 'translate(450px) scale(0.7)',
                            '-ms-transform'     : 'translate(450px) scale(0.7)',
                            'transform'         : 'translate(450px) scale(0.7)',
                            'opacity'           : 0,
                            'visibility'        : 'hidden'
                        };
                        break;
                    case 'left':
                        return {
                            '-webkit-transform' : 'translate(-350px) scale(0.8)',
                            '-moz-transform'    : 'translate(-350px) scale(0.8)',
                            '-o-transform'      : 'translate(-350px) scale(0.8)',
                            '-ms-transform'     : 'translate(-350px) scale(0.8)',
                            'transform'         : 'translate(-350px) scale(0.8)',
                            'opacity'           : 1,
                            'visibility'        : 'visible'
                        };
                        break;
                    case 'right':
                        return {
                            '-webkit-transform' : 'translate(350px) scale(0.8)',
                            '-moz-transform'    : 'translate(350px) scale(0.8)',
                            '-o-transform'      : 'translate(350px) scale(0.8)',
                            '-ms-transform'     : 'translate(350px) scale(0.8)',
                            'transform'         : 'translate(350px) scale(0.8)',
                            'opacity'           : 1,
                            'visibility'        : 'visible'
                        };
                        break;
                    case 'center':
                        return {
                            '-webkit-transform' : 'translate(0px) scale(1)',
                            '-moz-transform'    : 'translate(0px) scale(1)',
                            '-o-transform'      : 'translate(0px) scale(1)',
                            '-ms-transform'     : 'translate(0px) scale(1)',
                            'transform'         : 'translate(0px) scale(1)',
                            'opacity'           : 1,
                            'visibility'        : 'visible'
                        };
                        break;
                };

            }
            else {

                switch( position ) {
                    case 'outleft'  : 
                    case 'outright' : 
                    case 'left'     : 
                    case 'right'    :
                        return {
                            'opacity'           : 0,
                            'visibility'        : 'hidden'
                        };
                        break;
                    case 'center'   :
                        return {
                            'opacity'           : 1,
                            'visibility'        : 'visible'
                        };
                        break;
                };

            }

        },
        _navigate           : function( dir ) {

            if( this.supportTrans && this.isAnim )
                return false;

            this.isAnim = true;

            switch( dir ) {

                case 'next' :

                    this.current    = this.$rightItm.index();

                    // current item moves left
                    this.$currentItm.addClass('dg-transition').css( this._getCoordinates('left') );

                    // right item moves to the center
                    this.$rightItm.addClass('dg-transition').css( this._getCoordinates('center') ); 

                    // next item moves to the right
                    if( this.$nextItm ) {

                        // left item moves out
                        this.$leftItm.addClass('dg-transition').css( this._getCoordinates('outleft') );

                        this.$nextItm.addClass('dg-transition').css( this._getCoordinates('right') );

                    }
                    else {

                        // left item moves right
                        this.$leftItm.addClass('dg-transition').css( this._getCoordinates('right') );

                    }
                    break;

                case 'prev' :

                    this.current    = this.$leftItm.index();

                    // current item moves right
                    this.$currentItm.addClass('dg-transition').css( this._getCoordinates('right') );

                    // left item moves to the center
                    this.$leftItm.addClass('dg-transition').css( this._getCoordinates('center') );

                    // prev item moves to the left
                    if( this.$prevItm ) {

                        // right item moves out
                        this.$rightItm.addClass('dg-transition').css( this._getCoordinates('outright') );

                        this.$prevItm.addClass('dg-transition').css( this._getCoordinates('left') );

                    }
                    else {

                        // right item moves left
                        this.$rightItm.addClass('dg-transition').css( this._getCoordinates('left') );

                    }
                    break;  

            };

            this._setItems();

            if( !this.supportTrans )
                this.$currentItm.addClass('dg-center');

        },
        _startSlideshow     : function() {

            var _self   = this;

            this.slideshow  = setTimeout( function() {

                _self._navigate( 'next' );

                if( _self.options.autoplay ) {

                    _self._startSlideshow();

                }

            }, this.options.interval );

        },
        destroy             : function() {

            this.$navPrev.off('.gallery');
            this.$navNext.off('.gallery');
            this.$wrapper.off('.gallery');

        }
    };

    var logError            = function( message ) {
        if ( this.console ) {
            console.error( message );
        }
    };

    $.fn.gallery            = function( options ) {

        if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {

            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );

            this.each(function() {

                var instance = $.data( this, 'gallery' );

                if ( !instance ) {
                    logError( "cannot call methods on gallery prior to initialization; " +
                    "attempted to call method '" + options + "'" );
                    return;
                }

                if ( !$.isFunction( instance[options] ) || options.charAt(0) === "_" ) {
                    logError( "no such method '" + options + "' for gallery instance" );
                    return;
                }

                instance[ options ].apply( instance, args );

            });

        } 
        else {

            this.each(function() {

                var instance = $.data( this, 'gallery' );
                if ( !instance ) {
                    $.data( this, 'gallery', new $.Gallery( options, this ) );
                }
            });

        }

        return this;

    };

})( jQuery );





$(function() {
$('#dg-container').gallery({
autoplay : true
});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jg1hd3ta/)

This is the function where a timer is set. After the set amount of time passes, the code inside of `setTimeout` fires again. This is where you want to put your callback. I just check that the callback function exists and fire if so.

```
    _startSlideshow     : function() {

        var _self   = this;

        this.slideshow  = setTimeout( function() {

            _self._navigate( 'next' );

            if (_self.options.cb) {
                _self.options.cb();
            }

            if( _self.options.autoplay ) {

                _self._startSlideshow();

            }

        }, this.options.interval );

    },
```

Now you can pass in the callback as an option:

```
$('#dg-container').gallery({
  autoplay : true,
  cb : function() {
    console.log('callback fired!');
  }
});
```

If you want the callback on the trailing edge of the transition, fire the callback when the animation finishes instead. This plugin is using css animations. The browser fires an event when a css animation finishes. This portion is firing a function on that event.

```
        this.$wrapper.on( 'webkitTransitionEnd.gallery transitionend.gallery OTransitionEnd.gallery', function( event ) {

            _self.$currentItm.addClass('dg-center');
            _self.$items.removeClass('dg-transition');
            _self.isAnim    = false;

            if (_self.options.cb) {
              _self.options.cb();
            }

        });
```